# ¿Por qué no me llegan los valores de AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo la siguiente función con la cual quiero obtener un ID directamente de mi base de datos pero no recibe el dato mi PHP.

Les comparto a continuación el código que estoy implementando.

```
 function obtenerId(id) {
        var ID = id;
        var data = ID;
        //document.getElementById('titulo_comprobacion').innerHTML = ID;
        $.ajax({
            url: "lib/controladores/consultaTramite.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        })
    }

<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];

print_r ($id);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error en consola?

Comment: negativo, muestra el valor de la variable pero en php no la recibe

Comment: ¿Cómo llamas a esa función?

Comment: Tengo un botón: `<i id="ok" class="material-icons uk-text-primary md-icon uk-form-file " onclick="obtenerId(${id})" href="#modal-full" uk-toggle >search</i>`

Comment: debería agregar también su archivo "consultaTramite.php" para ver como lo esta recibiendo y como o retorna a la petición AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sucede que no se envía datos porque no está correctamente definido el parámetro.

Cuando se utiliza AJAX, los parámetros van en un objeto cuyas propiedades están formato Json, esto se entenderá mejor con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
var data = { 
             "clave":"valor", 
             "ID":1, 
             "user": "arglez35"
           } ;
```

Aplicando esta teoría a tu código, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
function obtenerId(id) {
        var ID = id;
        var data = { "id": ID};
        //document.getElementById('titulo_comprobacion').innerHTML = ID;
        $.ajax({
            url: "lib/controladores/consultaTramite.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        })
    }

<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];

print_r ($id);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar algo de explicación a tu respuesta?

Comment: claro hermano, ahora mismo edito la respuesta :D

Comment: tambien crei que era por eso, pero resulta que no

Comment: dale un console.log(id); antes de que vaya por la consulta AJAX. Sólo por curiosidad

Comment: con `console.log(id);` si me muestra el valor correcto pero si hago: `console.log(data);` no muestra nada

Comment: ¿Has intentado con un echo?

Comment: efectivamente, el problema es que a mi php no llega el valor que hay en "data" probé si tenia algun error en la ruta de mi archivo PHP pero si está bien

Comment: hice una actualización más. Por cierto, ¿Conoces Postman?

Comment: Solo para añadir una alternativa similar a Postman, recomiendo Insomnia REST.

Comment: No amigo, ahorita reviso a ver qué tal